# simple percentage update

Tags: sql

I need to calculate the credit_total column to reflect 10% of the invoice_total. I request the kind assistance of the community.

```
UPDATE invoices
SET credit_total = '.10'
WHERE invoice_number = 'AX-014-027';
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `*`:

```
UPDATE invoices
    SET credit_total = invoice_total * 0.10
    WHERE invoice_number = 'AX-014-027';
```

Comment: OMG so close thank you very much banging my head over the percentage how to write it thank you thank you thank you